# Concerning the nonlinear functional equation $f(x)f(x) =x+1+f(x+1)$

Tags: functional-equations

There's a problem I've been working on for awhile that involves some hefty functional equations. For example, I may have something along the lines of

$$
f(x)f(x) =x+1+f(x+1)
$$

I've tried several different methods of attack (the farthest I ever got was probably with a power series which didn't yield a recurrence relation)  but it never amounts to much. As if that wasn't bad enough, I don't actually know any values of $f(x)$, other than that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$. The thing is, I don't actually care about $f(x)$, I only want to know $f(0)$ (analytically) but I can never seem to get two equations for a given point.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to solve this, or even just some insight into whether or not it *can* be solved. Thanks!

**Edit: Additional facts**

- It can be required that $1<f(0)<2$
- $f(x)$ is strictly increasing
- $f(x)$ is non-negative

Comment: Does $f(x)f(x)$ just mean $f(x)^2$?

Comment: Yes! For some reason I thought it would be less ambiguous that way.

Comment: When you write $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$, do you mean $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x),\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)$, or both ? This is an important distinction here

Comment: I mean that $f(x)$ goes to positive infinity as $x$ goes to positive infinity.

Comment: Also see my question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/864262/nonlinear-inhomogeneous-recurrence-fx2-fx1sx-to-find-nested-radical), which generalizes this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constraints are not strong enough to impose a unique value to $f(0)$.  In fact, I show below that there for every value $a$ between $1.8$ and $2$ there is a solution with $f(0)=a$ (in fact  for a given $a$ there are uncoutably many such solutions, as our construction will show).

Given a function $\phi : [0,1[ \to {\mathbb R}$, there is a unique solution $f: [0,+\infty[ \to {\mathbb R}$ to the functional equation that coincides with $\phi$ on $[0,1[$.  Indeed, we will have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f(x)&=&\phi(x-1)^2-x=\phi_1(x) \ \ (\text{for }\ x\in[1,2[) \\
f(x)&=&\phi_1(x-1)^2-x=\phi_2(x) \ \ (\text{for }\ x\in[2,3[) \\
\end{array}\tag{1}
$$
and so on.

Now, let $a \in [1.8,2]$ and let $\phi : [0,1] \to {\mathbb R}$ be a continuous, strictly increasing map satisfying the boundary conditions $\phi(0)=a, \phi(1)=a^2-1$ (so for example you could take $\phi$ affine, or trigonometric, etc).

Then the $f$ uniquely defined by (1) will also be continuous and strictly increasing (in particular, $f$ will be positive). 
So all we need to show is that $f \to +\infty$ at $+\infty$ ; since $f$ is strictly increasing, it suffices to show that $f(n) \to +\infty$ when $n$ is an integer.

We have 
$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
f(1)&=&f(0)^2-1 \geq 1.8^2-1=2.24 \\
f(2)&=&f(1)^2-2 \geq 2.24^2-2=3.0176 \geq 3 \\
f(3)&=&f(2)^2-3 \geq 3^2-2=6 \\
\end{array}\tag{1}
$$

We can then use mathematical induction : let us show that $f(k) \geq k$, for every $k\geq 3$.

The $k=3$ case has just been checked. Suppose that the hypothesis is true for some $k\geq 3$.
  We have

$$f(k+1)=f(k)^2-(k+1) \geq k^2-(k+1)=k-2+(k-1)^2 \geq k-2+4=k+2 \geq k+1 $$

So the hypothesis holds on the next level. This shows that $\lim_{+\infty}(f)=+\infty$ as wished.

Comment: Wow, that's amazing! Actually, it's possible for me to impose that $1<f(0)<2$. There are a few other known facts that I didn't mention because I didn't think they were important, but I realize know that they probably are to people who know much more about this sort of thing than I do. I've put them all in the original post.

Comment: @Mr.G : I updated my answer to meet all your additional conditions.

Comment: Is there another condition I could find that would force a unique $f(0)$ (short of finding the $f(x)$ at another point?) I know that $f(0)$ has one single value but from what I'm understanding of your answer, the information contained in the functional equation alone (plus the auxiliary facts) isn't enough to extract it.

Comment: @Mr.G : well, it looks like there’s a piece of information you forgot to add. How exactly do you know that “f(0) has one single value” ?

Comment: $f(x) = \sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{x+3+...}}}$

My idea was to convert it to a functional equation to try to solve it and get it to look like something more recognizable.

Comment: @Mr.G : I see. When you say you want to “know $f(0)$ analytically”, you mean you're looking for a series expansion for $f(0)$ ?

Comment: I want to find a closed-form expression for $f(0)$. Pretty much anything other than $f(0) = \sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+...}}}$ would be progress at this point.

Comment: I find it very puzzling, that $f(0)$ can be chosen freely, because any solution $f(x)$ should equal $f(x)=\sqrt{x+1+\sqrt{x+2+\sqrt{x+3+...}}}$ (this follows by iterative application of the equation) and hence $f(0)=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+...}}}$ should follow also straight from the equation. Where is my mistake?